# MicroStrategy Installation

Tags: linux, centos, centos5

I'm installing MicroStrategy 9 (CentOS 5.5) and its currently failing looking for the mstrfixprot program.  Has anyone else had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the late answer on this I figured it out.  It turns out MicroStrategy is not supported on CentOS and my install did not have dev tools installed on it.  MicroStrategy requires having bc, dc, and a bunch of the other old linux tools that are always defaulted on a fresh RHEL 5.

Answer (score 1):

I don't even know what this "MicroStrategy" ***is***, but I found (by Google) someone had similar issues: https://resource.microstrategy.com/Forum/ReplyListPage.aspx?id=5095.

Looks like a support forum from the software developer... try asking there, maybe they can help you better.